# Session management - Web server or application server?

Tags: security, session, server, webserver

In terms of security, what's the best place to implement session management, on a webserver or application server? Or does it depend on the technology. If later is the case, any idea which technology (webserver or application server) proves to be best so far with least issues reported and which one had the most bugs found?

What about other factors like performance, reliability and easiness of implementing?

I am debating between flask and apache...